# Why is my if statement true when it should be false

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

My if statement is returning the wrong values:

```
for i in range (3325 , 3325+1):
    FSBRID = []
    for j in range(93, 94):
        a = ws1.cell(row=i, column=j)
        print(a.value)
        if 'SOIL' or 'soil' in a.value:
            print('wrong')
```

The returned values:

```
TISSUE 
wrong

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the `or` statement. Your condition can be rewritten `if ('SOIL') or ('soil' in a.value):`, the first part of the condition will always be `True` since it is a non-empty string

Comment: No, it should be `if 'SOIL' in a.value or 'soil' in a.value` if the desired effect is to check if either 'SOIL' or 'soil' occur in a.value.

Comment: You have to check both the words separately with a or in between
`("soil" in a.value) or ("SOIL" in a.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct

```
if 'SOIL' or 'soil' in a.value:
```

is parsed as though it were

```
if ('SOIL') or ('soil' in a.value):
```

and non-empty strings are true, making it equivalent to

```
if True or ('soil' in a.value):
```

One solution is to split it into two “in” operators, the results of which is combined.

```
if 'SOIL' in a.value or 'soil' in a.value:
```